# When is a referenced texture actually loaded?

Tags: unity-game-engine

i have a script attached to a gameobject that has a reference to a texture.

The gameobject is not enabled at start so my question is:

when is the texture actually loaded into memory? When the gameobject is enabled or when the scene loads?

Answer (score 0):

You can test this. You create a gameobject with a script on it has the reference to the texture as public variable and disable the gameobject. Then you create another gameobject that also has a script an tries to access the reference to the texture in the other script. E.g. I did a little test with a prefab.

Gameobject 1, disabled and with this script attached to it:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class ScriptOne : MonoBehaviour
{
    // reference to the prefab/texture
    public GameObject prefab;

    // Not called since the object is disabled
    // will be called as soon as gameobject 1 gets enabled
    private void Awake()
    {
        Debug.Log("prefab: " + prefab);
    }
}
```

Gameobject 2, enabled and with this script attached to it:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class ScriptTwo : MonoBehaviour
{
    // Reference to gameobject 1
    public GameObject other;

    private void Awake()
    {
        Debug.Log("other: " + other.GetComponent<LoadOrderTest>().prefab);
    }
}
```

This will lead to a valid output in the console (other: ...).

If you are asking this because you want to have them loaded only when they are needed (to save memory if you really have to), then you will have to load them on runtime with "Resources.Load" in Awake or OnEnable.

Comment: i've thought about testing this way but i immediately assumed that there may be a special condition for texture2d/texture that enable the actual load in the get-er. That's how i would've done it, and maybe provide a special option to load on scene start. @Gunnar B.

Comment: Maybe this answers your question http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/720471/does-unity-load-in-memory-textures-that-are-target.html